# How can I export these Sql Server 2008 Tables from SqlServer A to SqlServer B?

Tags: sql-server-2008, export

I'm trying to export some tables from a sql database on *SqlServer 1*. In our intranet LAN (right next to me) is a temp Sql Server I made, called *SqlServer 2*.

I don't want to backup the entire db and then restore that : source DB is around 30Gig.

So I try and do an EXPORT task. But some of the tables have some GEOGRAPHY fields. So the Export Task isn't working. Is there any other way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have administrator rights on *SQLServer1*, you could create a linked server object on *SQLServer1* that points to *SQLServer2*.  With that relationship, you can use a four-part name to reference the tables on *SQLServer2* and write an INSERT statement to push the data over.

Check out [Books Online](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188279.aspx) for how to set up a linked server.

Comment: Right now, i don't have admin on *SqlServer 1* I could maybe get it .. but I'm hoping not to, just yet. If there's another way....

Comment: You could go the other way - create the linked server on *SqlServer2* to point at *SqlServer1*.  You won't need admin permissions on *SqlServer1* for that.  You would just need SELECT permissions on the tables you are extracting from.

Comment: OK - gave that a go. Error : `Objects exposing columns with CLR types are not allowed in distributed queries. Please use a pass-through query to access remote object '"SourceDBName"."dbo"."SourceTableName"'.` ??? Remember, I said some tables have `GEOGRAPHY` fields. I'm guessing this is what the error is all about?

Comment: OK - sorry - learned something new.  Here's a link to the solution.  I was close, but you can write the query differently to get it to work.  http://geographika.co.uk/copying-spatial-data-between-sql-server-databases